# How to set up prefixes on saved search for multiple choices in netsuite?

Tags: netsuite, saved-searches

I have a multiple select field that allows multiple selections of colors. I created a formula that would append a prefix of "color-" to each selected list, but it only appends it to the the beginning of the field. I'm not sure how I can split the field results up for the formula to where I can get it showing up for all results.

CASE WHEN {custitemtag_color1} is NULL 
THEN '' 
ELSE    'color-'||{custitemtag_color1} 
END

Results with multiple selections show: color-Black,Lime Green,White

Expected Results need to show: color-Black,color-Lime Green,color-White

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening is that NetSuite returns "Black,Lime Green,White" as a single result for the multi-selection, then you're prepending "color-" to that text returned.  To work around it within your saved search, you could simply replace any instances of the comma (",") with ",color-":

```
CASE WHEN {custitemtag_color1} is NULL THEN '' ELSE 'color-'|| REPLACE({custitemtag_color1}, ',', ',color-') END
```